# Docker container exits with code 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I know this question has been asked multiple times and I've looked at a number of them here but I still can't figure this out.

I have an extremely simple docker-compose.yml file which loads up 3 image: nginx, php7 and postgresql.

Those 3 are linked so that I have a LAPP stack (yes,I realise I'm using an old version, I'll upgrade as soon as I can wrap my head around the basics).

This does work, except that my php code is a bind mounted volume and it ends up with the wrong file ownership in the container.

I tried changing my compose file to not load nginx using image but to rather build it from a Dockerfile (sorry if my jargon is not correct, I'm still learning about docker).

When I change it to use the docker file it and I do docker-compose up it does start up but the web container dies almost immediately.

Question:
Why does this work without the docker file and what must I do to make the container stay up if I do need to use a docker file.

```
web:
 build: './docker/nginx'
 #image: nginx:latest   # works if I load nginx like this and comment out the above line
 stdin_open: true
 tty: true
 ports:
 - "8080:80"

 volumes:
  - ./code:/code
  - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf

 links:
 - php

php:
 #image: php:7-fpm
 build: './docker/php'

 links:
 - postgres

 volumes:
  - ./code:/code

postgres:
 image: postgres:latest

 environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=un_rftags
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pwd_RFT@gs01
  - POSTGRES_DB=db_rftags

 ports:
 - "9090:5432"
```

and my nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN mkdir -p /code && chown www-data /code -R
```

Comment: what is docker logs container-id showing for the nginx container, just exit 0?

Comment: Hi Ivthillo, I can't get them because the container shuts so quickly. I have figured out what the issue is. The nginx Dockerfile RUNs my chown command which causes the container to terminate as the script has ended (so its replacing whatever nginx do to keep the container going). I don't know how to fix that properly so I've come up with a work around. In my docker-compose.yml file I now have another build command called throwaway which builds the dockerfile listed above. In other words I load two nginx containers.. The throw away one to set permission and the "real" one which keeps running

Comment: Okay, good to hear you found it ps: docker logs container-id also works on containers which are stopped (docker ps -a to find their id)